# Ability for Admin to Link Social Media to a User's Account

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, redux

I'm faced with the current dilemma. My application flow is as follows:

- Admin logs in
- Has to select a list of clients
- The selected Client data is then loaded in
- Admin should now be able to Link Facebook, for example, to that
  client's account with their credentials on a click of a button. Same 
  would apply for other social media accounts that the user has. The
  reason that's important is the app then goes and fetches data from
  their social media, such as Facebook Insights.

Is there a way I could achieve is ? I was thinking maybe Auth0 but I had a look on their documentation and it seems I could do it but only if Admin was the one linking his own social media account to his account. Can't really see a way where he could link other accounts to the Client's account currently selected.

I'm working with a React-Redux, Express and MongoDB app.

Even a push in the direct direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is certainly achievable using Auth0 - take a look at the Link Accounts API (User) - you want to use the second option using an API v2 token - https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/post_identities

Comment: I would first need to use the Authentication API right, in order to make a twitter account for them and then use the Management API to link the Twitter account with the Username and Password one. Am I on the right track ?

Comment: Yes, you would need minimum of two User Profiles in Auth0 (get created automatically when you login with a social account such as Twitter). You can signup using auth0 lock widget, or create a DB user from the User section of Auth0 Dashboard and so on. You are definitely on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly achievable using Auth0 - take a look at the Link Accounts API (User) - you want to use the [second option using an API v2 token](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/post_identities)

See sample [here](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-link-accounts-sample/tree/master/RegularWebApp) that illustrates how this might work using Node.js.

You could possibly rework this to your technology stack pretty easily. Since you are using a Management Token you'd want that to remain server side (Express) and the react/redux app could make ajax calls via the Express Server side component - which in turn calls out to the Auth0 endpoint to perform the user search / linking actions.

Comment: Yes, that's the exact flow I wanted. Gonna have a look at those docs and figure out how to do it. Having a look at the Management API, that expects there to already be a user account with the same email address but linked to twitter, correct ? And then with the Management API you merge the two into the one account. Is that correct ?

Comment: Pleased this helps. In order to account link "automatically" (programatically using decision logic) there needs to be some correlating attribute for you to make the decision with e.g the email on the DB connection matches the email on social connection (eg. twitter etc).  But if you are manually doing the account linking as an Admin - you can arbitrarily link any two accounts you choose - so long as you have their UserIDs and a Mgmt Token as I mention in the answer. In that situation there does not need to be a matching attribute (eg. same email).

Comment: This helps so much. Thank you, really, thank you. I feel like I finally had a breakthrough and I'm heading on the right track.